C++ Unions: Accessing non-active array element guaranteed to not share space
Consider the following C++ union:
struct Mystruct
{
    char     *p;   // sizeof(p) == 8, alignof(p) == 8
    uint32_t  sz;  // sizeof(sz) == 4, alignof(sz) == 4
};                 // sizeof(MyStruct) == 16 (with padding),
                   // alignof(MyStruct) == 8

union U
{
    MyStruct s;
    char     buf[16]; 
};

My question is can I safely read the last element only of buf[] even when buf[] is not the last written to (active) member of the union? I believe that based on the way unions must work in any compiler implementation this element (buf[15]) can never be overwritten by any write to the MyStruct s. Is that correct?
The primary objective is to be as space-efficient as possible while also working reliably.
What I'm doing: This union is the sole data member for a string class (we'll call it MyString). Within that string class the MyStruct struct (actually called AllocInfo) when used contains a pointer to and length of a dynamically allocated block of memory for the string (char* and uint32_t, respectively) when a string larger than 15 characters is stored. buf[] is used for short string optimization (SSO): the string is directly stored in this buffer if it will fit (15 or fewer characters). The last element of this char array is used as a flag. When SSO is used it is set to 0 and also doubles as the terminating null character of the string when the length of the stored string is exactly 15. When dynamically allocated memory is used this flag is set to 1. When I need to read the string I always read this flag first to determine how to access it.
Constraints: I am targeting C++11. Currently I am compiling on AMD64 Linux but I'm attempting to be as platform-agnostic as possible with an eye on compiling for ARM64 Linux at some point soon (the actual size of the buf[] char array is calculated at compile time to be guaranteed to always be at least one byte larger than the struct and also to align to alignof(max_align_t) for the platform). I am linking with no libraries at all. This means I can't use anything in the Standard C or Standard C++ Libraries nor anything in the std:: namespace.

My understanding is that because I sometimes read the flag in buf[15] when the last member of the union written to was the MyStruct struct that is by definition Undefined Behavior (for C++11). I get that. However I also believe that the behavior in this particular case must be deterministic and do what I want because of the requirements for unions (union members share space and starting address). Am I correct in that assumption?
In cases like this where individually accessed elements of an array in a union do not themselves share space with any other member of the union (because the starting address of the element is past the last address used used by any other union member) should that really be UB in C++?
As far as I am able to ascertain the code does work perfectly with no issues on both GCC and Clang. Compiling with every warning flag and strictness level I can think of turned on, at the highest optimization level outputs no diagnostics and the code runs as expected. However compilers aren't required to emit a diagnostic for UB so I can't infer anything from that, correct?
I could, of course, pull the flag out of the union and put it elsewhere in the string class. But doing that would mean that I can no longer use 100% of the size of the string instance for SSO which would make it a little slower and a little less space efficient in some cases which makes me sad. It could also mean increasing the sizeof(MyString) (currently 16) or making the string class itself not as space efficient in memory when many instances are dynamically allocated.

Is there a non-UB way to do what I'm doing while still allowing class instances to be just as space efficient?
Since everything seems to work as is should I just stop overthinking it?

C++20 introduced implicit lifetime types so I'm not sure how that interacts with the rules anymore but pre C++20 type punning through a union is UB.

Don't use (untagged) unions in C++, accessing inactive members is UB and unions cannot be used for type punning (you have to use memcpy for that)

In standard C++, that is UB, no way around it. Whatever any specific compiler does is up to that specific compiler. Whether you can rely on a compiler "to do a sensible thing" is up to you. I would not if I assume the code will live through at least one compiler's major version upgrade.

@NathanOliver: I'm not sure that this would actually qualify as type punning. I am not trying to access the data of any union member by reading a different union member.

Maybe it is ok to read byte representation of the whole union U with reinterpret_cast. It's not a strict aliasing violation, but I'm not sure whether it's ok to access byte representation of an inactive member.

@PepijnKramer: I'm not sure that this would actually qualify as type punning. I am not trying to access the data of any union member by reading a different union member.

@CarlE.Thompson If I understand correctly, you still read from an inactive member (which would be UB too).

@PepijnKramer: Yes, reading from the inactive member is UB. That's why I posted this question!

You could create a class, which uses a byte array as storage and for each access the data is unpacked either as s or as buf. The optimizer would hopefully remove that unpacking.

@Sebastian: Yes, that's a solution too. I'd probably use a char array because the standard is clear that accessing other data through a char array doesn't cause aliasing issues but it is not clear that a byte array must be treated the same way. And I would use the memcpy() technique for the unpacking. However, I prefer not to use that approach because IMO it's not as readable.

since C++17 std::byte is also allowed. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast BTW signed char not necessarily, because char can be unsigned. char is fine.

@Sebastian: std::byte is part of the Standard C++ Library which I'm not using. It's not part of the core language itself. I'd guess std::byte is usually implemented as a char type.

The last 4 bytes of your struct DO technically share storage with the last 4 bytes of the char array, because the struct is padded and its size is 16 bytes. When you write your struct, the compiler is completely free to overwrite those padding bytes with anything. It's also free to not modify them.
As a naive example, consider that the struct could be read into a 128-bit register or two 64-bit registers, modified and then written back to memory. Those last 4 bytes are "don't cares", and the compiler is under no obligation to preserve their value.
You may wish to take control over this by ensuring all bytes of your struct are defined:
struct Mystruct
{
    char     *p;
    uint32_t  sz;
    char      padding[3]; // unused
    char      flag;       // zero if SSO, non-zero otherwise
};

union U
{
    MyStruct s;
    char     buf[16]; 
};

Now flag will share the same storage location as buf[15], and (ignoring aliasing issues) you can query either.
If you want to take it a step further, consider avoiding aliasing issues by not using the union at all. Just use the struct, because it's not a strict aliasing violation to read/write the data occupied by MyStruct via a char pointer.
So you could have this kind of setup, which is essentially a 'manual' union:
struct MyString
{
    operator char*() { return flag ? data : (char*)this; }

private:
    char     *data;
    uint32_t  sz;
    char      padding[3]; // unused
    char      flag;       // zero if SSO, non-zero otherwise
};

static_assert(sizeof(MyString) == 16);


I like your last no union needed approach. (In fact someone else posted pretty much the exact same code elsewhere.) Your modification of of my union approach appears to suffer the same problem as the original even if the flag can be accessed in both places: when accessing a string you initially don't know which member is active so you don't know which version of the flag to use. No matter which you pick it could be the inactive one. I'll go with your no union approach. It's pretty much the same as what I'm already doing and reasonably clear to read. Thank you!

Yes, that's the problem with unions, but in practice it's often "fine". The point was to avoid the totally undefined behavior issues that you had and improve them to "technically" undefined behavior. But yeah, there's no real need for this, given the no-union approach has defined behavior.

My original code worked perfectly so it too had just "technically" undefined behavior.

Now that I think of it isn't the no union approach also technically UB because it fails the strict aliasing rule? (Also I'm not sure that using this rather than data as the address casted to would work on all implementations... I could imaging a compiler making a virtual table pointer the first invisible data member of the class instance.)

I'm pretty sure the standard requires that the first data member is at the same address of the object. Strict aliasing does not prevent you from accessing the data from an object via a char pointer. This is why memcpy is the typical solution for type punning.

I just did a quick test on both GCC and Clang and they both put the virtual pointer first in the object so using this definitely doesn't work in cases where the class has any virtual functions. You might want to edit  your answer so that people who see it don't get the wrong idea. Also your union approach still has UB just like my original so you might want to remove it from your answer so people don't get confused and think that one is a solution. Anyway, thanks again for the answer!

Why would you add virtual methods to this though? And anyway, doing so would fail the static assertion. If you want this behavior inside a class with virtual methods, store the struct as a data member of that class.

Classes with virtual functions are quite common in C++ for any number of reasons. I wouldn't assume that people don't use them. And in real life I wouldn't hand-calculate the sizes and use an assert as then the code would likely not work on other platforms without modification. I would (and I did) have the compiler automatically calculate the proper sizes for everything at compile time so the code always works regardless of the compiler / platform. No assert is necessary.

The point I was trying to make is you don't need virtual methods on this class when it can be encapsulated in your actual string class as the data member. Then you can do whatever you want but continue using this struct internally (no matter what size/architecture it's designed for) without worrying about whether or not the encapsulating class has a vtable.
